# Three.js importing a camera from a FBX file

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera

i have to implement a binary FBX file for an anamorphic graphic (can't show it due to copyright) into a website. It is displayed as it nearly should and contains no animation but 4 cameras. It has however a special effect playing with the focal length of the perspective camera inside that FBX. 
i thought to access the camera with `camera = scene.getObjectByName('cam1')` via `THREE.LoadingManager.onLoad` event but three.js gives me a 'not instance of THREE.camera'- Error

now, since there is no FBXLoader doc, my question how do i import said camera(s) as or into a THREE.Camera instance?

here is the code i use:

```
    //[...]
     manager.onLoad = function () {
      console.log('Loading complete!');
      camera = scene.getObjectByName('cam1');
      console.log(camera)
    };
    //[...]
    var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader(manager);
    // loading fine blob
    loader.load('assets/Anamorphic.fbx', function(object) {
      object.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object);
      mixers.push(object.mixer);
      var action = object.mixer.clipAction(object.animations[0]);
      action.play();
      object.traverse(function (child) {
      if (child.isMesh) {
        child.castShadow = true;
        child.receiveShadow = true;
      }
    // console.log(child)
   });
   scene.add(object);
  });
```

Comment: You may want to file a bug, if you're confident the FBX file contains a camera but there is no camera in the output of `THREE.FBXLoader`. Perhaps verify with: `scene.traverse((node) => node.isCamera ? console.log('found camera') : null)`.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy thank you for your help, there is a camera, but how do i access it? because i need to change the focal length over time. when i use this: `manager.onLoad = function () {
    console.log('Loading complete!');
    scene.traverse((node) => {
      if (node.isCamera && node.name === 'cam1')
      camera = node
      controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    
      controls.update();
    });
    }` i get `three.js:21811 THREE.WebGLRenderer.render: camera is not an instance of THREE.Camera.` which is still my problem :(

Comment: I think you will need to update your question with complete code, there isn't enough here to debug that. JSFiddle, Codepen, or other live demo would be even better.